# Lightning Design System - VF Sorting Function

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, lightning-design-system, tablesorter

We're adding some additional functions to an older tool which was originally built using the Lightning Design System on Visualforce. The stakeholder is requesting a sort function on a datatable which allows them to sort based on the Column headers.

I know this is pretty straightforward in Lightning, but does anyone have a good workable client-side JS solution that they can point me to for implementing this? We're not in a position to convert this tool to Lightning yet but I'd love to implement a Client side solution.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I've used [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) in Visualforce pages in the past. You get pagination and filtering more or less for free if you want those too.

A complication is handling the sorting of various data types - see [Client-side sorting and pagination of an apex:pageBlockTable – more on sorting](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable-more-on-sorting/) - because what is sorted is the rendered text string version of the values.

Comment: Great suggestion - just played around with it this morning and it meets my needs perfectly. Thanks!